# rdf4j: parse a sparql query to change some uri in the triple pattern

Tags: parsing, sparql, rdf4j

I would like to use RDF4J to parse a query to change some of the uris in the triple patterns. Could someone point me to some code please. I couldn't find anything.

Thank you
D063520

Comment: https://rdf4j.eclipse.org/javadoc/latest/org/eclipse/rdf4j/query/parser/sparql/SPARQLParser.html#parseQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: then cast it to a `ParsedTupleQuery` - then continue with whatever you want

Comment: By the way, in your previous question you said you already implemented a query visitor on the parsed query object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236961/rdf4j-parsedquery-or-tupleexpr-to-string-represenation - so why are you asking again, I don't the point of this question

Answer (score -1):

At the end I did the following ....

I implemented an `AbstractQueryModelVisitor` and I overwrote `meet(IsURI node)`.

This solved my problem.

Comment: I don't get it. This is literally what you already said in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58236961/rdf4j-parsedquery-or-tupleexpr-to-string-represenation) - did you really forget what you were doing 15 days ago?